# Testing multiple docker images with RSpec

Tags: docker, rspec

*Disclaimer: Am very new to ruby and rspec*

I've been attempting to build a private repo with docker images as base images for our different projects. We also trying to incorporate testing multiple docker images as part of the test suite.

We though have weird problem with `rspec`, it seems like tests run on the wrong docker machine.

Currently we have two docker images each on a separate folder

```
.
├── Dockerfile
├── Gemfile
├── Gemfile.lock
├── Jenkinsfile
├── README.md
├── Rakefile
├── nodejs
│   ├── 7.0
│   │   ├── Dockerfile
│   │   ├── README.md
│   │   └── spec
│   │       └── image_spec.rb
│   └── README.md
├── python
│   ├── 2.7
│   │   ├── Dockerfile
│   │   ├── README.md
│   │   ├── docker-entrypoint.sh
│   │   ├── requirements.txt
│   │   └── spec
│   │       └── image_spec.rb
│   └── README.md
└── spec
    └── spec_helper.rb
```

This is basically the structure we currently using, our `spec/spec_helper.rb` using default/simple

```
require 'serverspec'
require 'docker'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # Use color in STDOUT
  config.color = true

  # Use color not only in STDOUT but also in pagers and files
  config.tty = true

  # Use the specified formatter
  config.formatter = :documentation # :progress, :html, :textmate
end
```

And this is the `Rakefile` content we are using

```
require 'rake'
require 'rspec/core/rake_task'

RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:rspec) do |t|
  t.pattern = Dir.glob('*/*/spec/*_spec.rb')
  t.rspec_opts = '--format documentation --require spec_helper --color'
end

task :default => :spec
```

The problem we are facing, is that when we run `bundle exec rake rspec` the `python/2.7/spec_image.rb` tests are failing as we are sure they are running on `nodejs/7.0`. While when we run `bundle exec rspec python/2.7/spec/image_spec.rb` it would run successfully.

Here is also how `image_spec.rb` looks like for `python/2.7`

```
require 'serverspec'
require 'docker'

DOCKER_FOLDER = "python/2.7"
describe "Python/2.7 Specs" do

  before :all do
    add_simplejson_to_requirements

    image = Docker::Image.build_from_dir(DOCKER_FOLDER,  ARG: 'requirements.txt')

    set :path, '/usr/local/bin:$PATH'
    set :os, family: :alpine
    set :backend, :docker
    set :docker_image, image.id
  end

  #test for python version 2.7
  it 'has python 2.7 installed' do
    expect(command('python -c "import sys; print(sys.version_info[:])"').stdout).to include\
      '2, 7'
  end

  it 'installs requirements.txt given as --build-arg' do
    expect(command('pip install simplejson==3.6.3').stdout).to include\
     'Requirement already satisfied'
  end

end
```

Can someone please point us into the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone find this old thread, I ran into the same issue recently testing multiple images/containers. My solution was to add an `after(:all)` block that calls the `clear` method on the backend:

```
after(:all) do
  # Reset the docker backend so other images/containers can be tested.
  Specinfra::Backend::Docker.clear
end
```

It's a little smelly, but it does the trick. The better solution would be to create your own backend class and implement multi-image/container support from the start.